# How can I understand whether my C code is constant time or not?

Tags: c, timing-attack

I have a code for polynomial multiplication and it is written in C. I heard that whether a particular instruction is "constant time" can vary by architecture and by processor model and there isn't any official documentation for this behavior. How can I understand if my code is constant time or not?

Note: By "Constant time" I mean a software or code piece that are resistant to timing attacks. I am using UBUNTU on an intel i7 10th generation PC.

Comment: Have you already analyzed your algorithm assuming CPU instructions are constant time?

Comment: Check the processor reference manual for the CPU you are using, regardless what you "heard".  But note that an instruction which is constant on a hardware CPU may not be in a VM.

Comment: Can you share the instruction's code (or call, if it is from a lib)? Can you test it with different inputs and measure its time?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yes, I have many loops based on the parameters in it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. No I haven't analyzed my algorithm assuming the CPU instructions are constant time. Actually, I don't know how to properly analyze it have not done it before?  What I did is that I have  run the same code for the same inputs and measured cycle count and time  then I get more or less similar cycle counts  (but not exactly the same cycle count)

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Yes I can test it with different inputs and I did. I got similar (not exactly the same ) results for the same inputs. I measured the cycle counts.

Comment: @stark I will check it but is that enough to check the CPU instructions or should I also test my code if yes how should I test my code? I haven't done this  test before:(

Comment: Then you really should start from that and not about asking about instructions. Not to test, but analyze the time complexity. If you don't know how to do it, you will need to learn, it is not a simple thing to fit into SO answer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know the arithmetical complexity of my code. It is a logarithmic one

Comment: Generally, the concern about “constant time” in security code is that the time taken is independent of the data (including the cryptographic keys and the message data). If some algorithm takes logarithmic time or exponential time as a function of key length, that is okay (as long as the key length is a “fixed” length for the type of algorithm, not also a function of a particular key an individual user has generated).

Comment: Overall, the question of whether some code sequence is constant time in this regard is hard. You want to ensure the number of instructions does not change depending on the data, and the control path does not vary measurably (e.g., some branch might take path A or path B depending on a test, and path A and path B might have the same execution time, but the very act of branching may take more or less time to start path A than it does to start path B), and that each instruction’s execution time does not vary…

Comment: My code is not a full encryption code it is just a polynomial multiplication implementation that is used in that encryption protocol.  I just would like to figure out if my multiplication code solely  is constant time or not?

Comment: And the latter is not easy. Some instructions can vary in execution time depending on data. E.g., division instructions may have an “early out” for certain operands. Manufacturers are sensitive to these issues and may provide instructions intended to be constant-time. But then there are effects from cache behavior. Generally, it takes longer to load data that has not been used recently (because it is not in the cache) than to load data that has been used recently (because it is). So a cryptographic algorithm that uses data from different parts of an array depending on the data…

Comment: … being encrypted or decrypted may have varying execution times depending on the data.

Comment: Overall, it is essentially impossible for a novice to take some C code, learn some things about constant execution time, and modify the code to have constant execution time. It takes a lot of learning about processors, caches, other hardware, compilers, and so on, and even then it is fraught with hazards.

Comment: Can you sidestep the issue by adding some small random delay?

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks for your comments now I got an idea of how big my problem is. Do you say that even if it is stated as constant time in the reference manual of the CPU instructions  AND even my code is also fixed (getting rid of loops exc) it can still be  not constant time due to cache behaviour ?

Comment: @esra: Some processor manuals have some information about instruction timing. It is not always complete or correct. Sometimes the processor designers do not even know how long their instructions actually take. For example, an engineer might design an instruction so that it always takes, say, 17 cycles to complete. And it does. But it uses various resources during that time: some execution unit, some slot in a register file, et cetera. Maybe the instruction always finishes its last bit of work in 17 cycles, but sometimes, depending on the data, if gives up a slot in the register file early…

Comment: … Well, that means, in some circumstances, another instruction that was waiting for a slot in the register file can start executing early. So **that** instruction will finish at a different time, depending on the data, even though the first instruction finishes at the same time. So the fact that each and every instruction has a fixed amount of time from its start to its end does not mean the entire program has a fixed amount of time from its start to its end.

Comment: @but then how can we fully guarantee that the code is constant time? it seems impossible to measure all of these possibilities:(

Comment: @esra: It is indeed very difficult to make good cryptographic code, and flaws are discovered all the time. If you are doing this as a class assignment, the instructor will probably be satisfied with a “constant time” algorithm in the abstract C model, in a sense: Code that executes the same number of C operators (and of the same type) regardless of the data being encrypted/decrypted and the keys being used.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am a PhD student in cryptography but have not analyzed any code regarding timing-attacks yet. I am more into writing efficient implementation of the algorithms. I have actually developed a mathematically more efficient polynomial multiplication method and implemented in it C language. I observed %35  reduction 
 in cycle count and sent the results to a conference . One of the reviewers of the conference asked me if my code is constant time or not and I don't know how to answer it now:( But in cryptographic community they usually use Arm Cortex M4 assembly ...

Comment: @EricPostpischil ....instructions for implementation of the cryptographic protocols. I am working on a post-quantum cryptographic protocol NTRU Prime which is one of the NIST PQC standardization Process competitors. Since I do not have any background in Cortex M4 assembly language I could not answer that question properly now. My code is written in standard C language. Sometimes they use HAswell AVX2 instructions as well and I do not have enough background it either: I wish I had someone help me with the cortex m4 implementation then  this could be future work research paper too. So ..

Comment: @esra: For that purpose, you can separate the algorithm into a theoretical portion that implements the algorithm in some abstract machine and a practical portion in which that machine would be realized in real processor instructions. As long as the theoretical portion is constant time in the abstract machine and the abstract machine is reasonable, we can say the algorithm itself is constant time, and actually implementing it in constant time is a simple matter of programming (in assembly language, with cooperative processor manufacturers).

Comment: @esra: I do not work in cryptography regularly, but I would expect some researchers have defined some sort of computing model they use in their papers to talk about constant-time algorithms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240102/discussion-between-esra-and-eric-postpischil).

Answer (score 0):

This is only a little example, but on one security summer school I have been shown an example of timing attack scenario. It can easily happen when the **code performs cryptographic operations only after certain conditions are satisfied**. Consider such a snippet:

```
if (should_encrypt == 1) {
/*Do computationally heavy encryption operations*/
}
 else {
/*Do something else (no encryption)*/
}
```

Therefore, the attacker can observe the execution time of the program in both scenarios and deduce when the encryption might have happened. By making sure this is not the case in your code, you can protect your program from this particular timing attack vulnerability.

Comment: The question specifically asks about a processor instruction being constant time, not about whether the larger algorithm is constant time.